# Countdown Loop Bug

Tags: loops, countdown

I have to write a program that counts down from the given seconds to zero. 
I wrote this:
import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Counter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // prompt the user for input
        System.out.println("Start time in seconds");
        int seconds = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("00:"+seconds);

        for (int i =0; i>0; i-=1) {
        if (seconds<=0)
        System.out.println("00:" + i);
    }


    }
```

}

The output is only the given value and the loop does not print. How can I fix this?

Comment: it fails in your for loop. you set your i=0, then check if i>0.

Comment: Also, your test for `if (seconds<=0)` doesn't seem to make much sense, as you never change the value of `seconds`. Should the `0` in that test be `i` instead?